# Притяжательное местоимение или нет?

Tags: терминология, местоимение, классификация

Известно, что слово ***его*** - это либо родительный/винительный к местоимениям он и оно, либо (в лексикализованном значении) притяжательное местоимение к он, оно.

Вот предложение: ***Его*** превращение в пьяницу.

Слово ***его*** здесь — это притяжательное местоимения или субъектный родительный падеж при отглагольном существительном превращение?

Такое предложение можно сопоставлять с двумя типами конструкций:

Во-первых:

- Моё превращение в пьяницу
- Твоё превращение в пьяницу
- Его превращение в пьяницу

Тут слово ***его*** вроде как притяжательное местоимение, поскольку входит в своеобразную парадигму с "чистымы" притяжательными местоимениями мой и твой.

Но есть и другое сопоставление:

- ***Иван*** превратился в пьяницу ---> Превращение ***Ивана*** в пьяницу (Иван
  становится родительным субъктный)
- ***Я*** превратился в пьяницу ---> Превращение ***меня*** в пьяницу (личное местоимения я становится родительным субъектным)
- ***Он*** превратился в пьяницу ---> Превращение ***его*** в пьяницу (где местоимение его, стало быть, тоже  тяготеет к родительному
  субъектному падежу).

Что думаете?

Answer (score 1):

Ахаха, оставлю это тут:

> *"По которому ево доношению, его великого государя.."*

Его - это Эго, Он же божественный Дух. Его великого государя ~ Бога великого государь(го+сударь, судья Господа, ставленник божий). Принадлежащий Ему. Не государя - великого, а Бога великого, государя.

местоимения лиц:

**я - мы - ты - вы - он - она - оно - они(оне).**

местоимения личное и безличное(или может духовное и бездуховное?): **сам - само.**

Притяжательные местоимения вопрос **"чей/чья?"** (личный? относящийся ко мне):

мой/моя/мои - наш - твой - ваш - его - ея - оной/иной/ - ихний - свой,

Выдохнули? тогда дальше, вторая часть, вопрос **"чьё/чьи?"** безличный, исходящий от меня:

моё/мои(принадлежащий мне) - наше/наши - твоё/твои - ваше/ваши - ево - её - оное/иное - их -  своё/свои.

И прикол в том, что они-то разные. **Мой - это не моё**). Почему приходится делить именно так? Потому что вот простой диалог:

-Дай чашку. - Не дам, моя. Чашка моя, но принадлежит мне, я распоряжаюсь чашкой, потому что она моя.

-Дай чашку. - Не дам, моё.(чашка - это моё) То есть чашка уже это, средний род, а не женский. То есть, есть местоимения возвратные личные, а есть обезличенные что ли. Я не распоряжаюсь чашкой, но чашка это моё. Собака на сене: трава не моя, а сено - моё, охраняю сено.

В английском языке первая группа называется притяжательные местоименные прилагательные, а вторая собственно притяжательные местоимения. И, если вы учили английский хотя бы один год, вы их знаете:

I - he - she - it - we - you - they

1-2: my-mine - his-his - her-hers - it-its - our-ours - your-yours - their-theirs

То есть они не стали заморачиваться и просто приписали одну букву, с ОН получился прокол, ну да фиг с ним, как у них раньше было не знаю. Хотя знаю немного, верну ТЫ:

ты = thou: thou - thy - thine.

Возвратные местоимения:

меня - нас - тебя - вас - него - неё - них - нет.

В английском возвратных нет, там есть **Reflexive - отраженные** то есть, они прибавляют Self:

myself - himself - herself - itself - yourself - ourself - themself

тут как бы уже начинаются проблемки, так как Ю - это Вы, множественное, а Ю-селф - это единственное. Тут как бы начинает давать сбой строгая логика английского.

У нас же пробелы заполняют сам и само:

Хотя тут лучше налить чайку и сделать перерыв, потому что маразм крепачает.

Начну сначала:

**сам - само - сами**

Притяжательные **"чей?"**:

свой - самый/самая(самоя)/самое

Притяжательные 2 безличное **"чьё/чьи?"**:

своё/свои - самоё/самои

Возвратные:

себя - нас - тебя - вас - самого - саму/cамую(самою) - самое - самих/самоих

В английском же тут проблемы, хотя там есть слово OWN - принадлежащий, собственный. OWN ~ себя.

Self в английском - это именно возвратное себя.

То есть в английском, есть два слова указателя - **себя-self и своё-own**. Так и живут люди. Хотя у них имеются кусочки возвратной формы творительного падежа:

**me-thee - мной-тобой**

Материал может дополняться)

А касательно вашего вопроса:

**Ево превращение в пьяницу.** - превращение чьё? - ево.

Наверное так корректно и снимает вопросы, что/чьё превратилось. Возвратное безличное местоимение.

Далее, о представленных типах конструкций:

> Моё превращение в пьяницу -

безличное, непредикативное.

> Превращение Ивана в пьяницу (Иван становится родительным субъктный) -

Субъектный кто? Что такое субъектный? Кто-то субъект? - нет тут субъекта, потому что Ивана - это дополнение и скорее объект воздействия, а не субъект, кто-то через превращение(предикация) сделал из Ивана пьяницу. (Кто-то) превратил муху в слона. Личная бессубъектная предикация. Пьянство превратило Ивана в животное - можно сделать Пьянство субъектом, обезличив предикацию.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147529/discussion-on-answer-by-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.